# How to dynamically use MOC depending on thread to protect core data

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, concurrency

I've read through the materials regarding core data and threading and understand the principles of a separate MOC for each thread. My question is, what's the best way to dynamically determine whether to use a different MOC or the main one. I have some methods that are sometimes called on the main thread, sometimes in background. Is dynamically detecting thread not recommended or is it okay? Any pitfalls? Or do people just write separate methods for the background processes?

Some additional detail...i have a refresh process that performs a bunch of updates off the main thread (so not to lock the UI while user is waiting) using a simple performSelectorInBackground. This process moves thru steps serially so i dont have to worry about multiple things accessing DB on THIS thread, obviously the trick is keeping the main and background safe. I have implemented using a separate context and merging in other places, but i recently rearchitected and am now using methods in the background i wasnt before. So i wanted to rewrite those, use the separate context, but sometimes ill be hitting them on the main thread and can access main MOC just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not give much detail about how you are managing your background operation and what you are doing with it, so it is pretty difficult to suggest anything.

In general, since creating a MOC is a pretty fast operation, you could create a new temporary MOC each time you need one in read-only mode (e.g. for data lookup). If you also have updates (e.g., adding new object or modifying existing ones), you should factor in the cost of merging, thus creating temporary MOCs each time could not be a good approach. 
Another good approach could be creating a child context in your background thread.
But, as I said, it all depends on what you are doing.

Have a look at this good post about multi-threaded Core Data usage: [Multi-Context CoreData](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/). It describes a couple of scenarios and the solutions for them.

EDIT:

You could certainly use `isMainThread` to discriminate between the two cases (where you can use the main MOC and when you need a new one). That is what that method is for (and it is surely not expensive).

On the other hand, if you want a cleaner implementation, the best approach IMO would be creating a child MOC (which simplifies a lot the merging process - it becomes almost automatic, since you just need to save the parent context after saving the temporary context).

Comment: thanks so much for the response. i tried to add some more detail to question. In my background refresh process, i both access and update the DB. Each time i create a new temporary MOC and use the didSave functionality to merge. I do have time where i just access, but only a couple updates, so would a new temp MOC be ok? ill take a look at the references you provided

Comment: thanks so much for the response! i havent played much with the child stuff, but that does seem to make a whole lot of sense. ill keep reading thru that link, but might try the thread check for my testing to see if that is whats causing the issue.

if i use the temp context/didSave approach for time being (behind on a deadline), how does merging work with user interacting with UI. do i need additional work to the MOCs or is didSave all you need for that approach?

Comment: You are welcome. I think the thread check is ok. If by "temp context/didSave" you mean what you are doing now (i.e., no child context), yes, handling the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` through a call to `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` is all you need to do. The link I provided above contains a reference implementation of that notification handler.

Comment: one more question, if you dont mind. can the merges happen quick enough for a user's scrolling performance? let's say the user initiates the refresh and is then scrolling thru the stories. when the refresh finishes and reloadData is called, how does the UI handle that? Do i need to do anything special or the changes will merge and theyll see the new stories if they scroll up or whatever. thanks so much

Comment: I think so. I mean, a merge can be seen as an "atomic" operation: before the merge, you do not have the new data; once the merge is completed, you get the new data in the main moc. If you reloadData (or otherwise update the content display) after the merge is done, you get the new data. The key point is, possibly, how you update your UI after the merge. but this is entirely a different issue...

Comment: ok, thanks again for the responses, i do appreciate it. could i ask about the UI update, i guess thats where im confused. ive got my data coming in and everything, but want to allow user to navigate through UI and just have data refresh when its done. can i just hide a reloadData behind a small notification on screen?

Comment: sorry, but more details are required. I tend to think that just reloading data when you get the notification of an update or new data should work. have no idea if that would work satisfactorily for your requirements...

Comment: thanks! i think its fairly simple. i just have a list of things in a tableview and im just thinking, if user is scrolling through those and in the background, that list that the user is scrolling through is updated, what to do. i can definitely call reloadData and then is the tableview smart enough to let the user keep scrolling and pop in the new data? sorry, happy to provide more, just let me know. and sorry to take this on and on, just so nice to have someone who responds as I'm a lone developer at my co.

Comment: you are welcome. you could try with reloadData, that's trivial to do. if it does not work as you like, you could try using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` -- also google: uitableview add row while scrolling...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a new `NSManagedObjectContext` for each thread, and you'll need to create new versions of your `NSManagedObject`s from that thread's new MOC. Read @sergio's answer regarding the pros/cons of that approach.

To check if you're on the main thread, you can use `[NSThread isMainThread]` and make determinations that way. Or, when you're spinning up a new thread to crunch on CoreData, also create a new MOC.

Comment: thanks so much for the response. i am currently creating a new MOC on the background thread and using the didSave functionality to merge. Is checking if its the main thread as you posted time consuming or inefficent or anything? i was trying to avoid rewriting a duplicate of  the method i currently have over again using the temp context code, but if thats what i have to, thats fine for now

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to associate each managed object context with a particular serial dispatch queue. So there's one for the main queue, and you can dynamically create them otherwise.

Once you're tying these things to queues, you can use [`dispatch_queue_set_specific`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_queue_set_specific) to attach a particular context to a particular queue and [`dispatch_get_specific`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_get_specific) to get the context for the current queue. They both turned up in iOS 5 so you'll see some iOS 4-compatible code that jumps through much more complicated hoops but you don't really need to worry about it any more.

Alternatively, if your contexts are tired to particular `NSRunLoop`s or `NSThread`s, store the context to `[[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary]` — it's exactly what it's there for.